# Action after .load() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After use this functionality:

```
var param = 'l=' + $('#refresh').val();
$('#ajax_reload').load(location.href, param);
```

I would like to change the bootstrap tab with:

```
$('a[href="#learntobe"]').tab('show');
```

But, if I fully understand, .load() break script executing. How can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `load` function provides a callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which will be executed when the asynchronous operations complete.  Something like this:

```
$('#ajax_reload').load(location.href, param, function () {
    $('a[href="#learntobe"]').tab('show');
});
```